# Unity 3D text disappears when I rotate the camera

Tags: unity-game-engine

New to Unity.

I think it's quite weird. What I was trying to do is to make the words on the newspaper flow like water. I created a plane for the newspaper, and I added a 3D Text object.

It worked well at first but when I rotate the camera(not the camera in the scene, but the camera with which you do all the editing), the text simply disappeared at some angles (particularly from below). The main camera had the same problem. It saw the text at some angle and couldn't at some other. I am sure that the texts are positioned right in the viewing frustum.

Some screenshots:

[The text can be seem from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHMM8.png)

[And it cannot be seen when the camera moves a little bit down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f3Xe.png)

[Or from another angle, the text is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r47RE.png)

[It is in the viewing frustum. But the main camera does not see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYm4V.png)

Comment: Try to move your text a bit closer to camera, just for 0.01, and check if you can reproduce the issue.

Comment: I tried several distances, from 0.01 to 20, and it doesn't help. But the angle from which you cannot see the text become large.

Comment: Sorry for dumb question — did you move text and newspaper, or text only? If newspaper and text will be on the exact same distance from the camera you will get something like "z-fighting" effect.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your text and background are on the exact same coordinates (for example 1,1,1). By doing so, you let Unity decide which is more important to show on the foreground, which makes it dissapear sometimes.

Try to move your text a little forward (for example 1,1,1.001), so it seems to rest on, instead of in the newspaper. Most of the time, that should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is there some kind of transparency on the object? 
Try to set it to opaque to check if this is the problem

Comment: Text is always transparent, and in fact, *must* be transparent in order to render properly.

Comment: There is a threeshold where an object is visible and then it isn't, like in this case. 
I don't know the solution, but I can say that the problem is the transparency...
I had the same problem with a rotating pair of glasses. The eyeglass frame was semi-transaprent and it just disappeared over a certain angle.